# how can I make each <tr> clickable in php?

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have the following code in php using laravel blade which allows me to get all the days of the current month as a table , I want to make each "" clickable with php , im not sure if thats possible.

```
    <table class="table-bordered">
  <tbody>
@php
$date = date('F Y');//Current Month Year
$row_count=0;
$col_count=0;

while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime(date('Y-m') . '-' . date('t', strtotime($date)))) {
if($row_count%4==0){
        echo "<tr>";
        $col_count=1;
     }
    $day_num = date('j', strtotime($date));
    $month_num = date('m', strtotime($date));
    $day_name = date('l', strtotime($date));
    $day_abrev = date('S', strtotime($date));
    $day = "$day_name $day_num";
    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
    echo '<td>' . $day . '</td>';
    if($col_count==4){
           echo "</tr>";
        }
        $row_count++; 
        $col_count++; 
}
@endphp
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: clickable as a button or a link. what do want to do with the click

Comment: as a button , i want to get the value on each <tr> i clicked @rootShiv

Comment: `tr` value or its html

Comment: i want to get the <tr> value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want make the `<tr>` clickable, just `echo "<tr onclick='your_js_function_name_or_code'>";`.

For example if you want alert, just `echo "<tr onclick='alert(1)'>";`.

Comment: thanks and is it possible getting the tr value with php ? or only with javascript ?

Comment: You can get the tr value when click it in javascript, and then pass it to your php with ajax. But if your tr value is never been changed in your html, you already got them in your php script when you echo them.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function using `onclick()`

```js
function showValue(value){
  alert(value)
  
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr onclick="showValue(1)">
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="showValue(1)">
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>
```